# How to reset the USB Drivers from within command prompt on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, usb, keyboard

I was using device manager to try and get my HP Windows 10 computer to work with a USB Device however realised that I had changed all the USB ports drivers. Upon restarting the computer, My mouse and keyboard stopped being recognised.

My keyboard and mouse work in BIOS mode and I am able to put the computer into recovery mode from which I am able to open the command prompt.

My question is, How do I reset the USB drivers to default from the command prompt? So that my computer can recognise my keyboard and mouse on startup?

Answer (score -1):

Enter `C:` in the Command Prompt.

Enter this command: `dism /image:c:\ /get-drivers`

Note down the Published Name for the USB driver.

Enter this command: `dism /image:c:\ /remove-driver /driver:oem0.inf`

Full procedure [here](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-uninstall-driver-using-command-prompt)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1102139)

Comment: Done, answer is updated now

Comment: Every system is going to be different.  The author's desired driver file isn't guaranteed to be `oem0.inf`.  Your answer does not make this fact clear.

Comment: Should I remove all class name USB drivers

Comment: Tried this but still did not work, so have now ended up resetting PC. Will see if this works.

Comment: SFC and DISM might correct the problem, finding correct drivers automatically. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/sfc-scannow-and-dismexe-online-cleanup-image/db3b24de-a261-403e-9d11-8141d13f7954